# Using selenium, how would I click delete and yes on reddit?

Tags: python, selenium

I am just trying to learn python by playing around with surfing the web just by using python. One thing I came across was that on some sites, they might have a hidden button.

For example, here on Reddit, if you go to your account page, and want to delete the first/top comment on your account page, you can easily find delete. The only problem is pressing the hidden button 'yes'.

The issue is that some posts have the ability to change some settings, such as disable inbox replies, delete, etc, and not all post have these same features/buttons.

They all have the same CSS selector of '`a.yes`', so even if you get all elements, with driver.find_elements, you couldn't get the button consistently because of the other buttons, like delete and disable inbox replies, etc.. As one page could be `elem[0] = delete.yes, elem[1] = disable inbox.yes` and another page could be `elem[0]~elem[4] = delete.yes`

The differences in the tags are:
delete button

```
<a href="javascript:void(0)" class="yes" onclick="change_state(this, &quot;del&quot;, hide_thing, undefined, null)">yes</a>
```

disable inbox replies

```
<a href="javascript:void(0)" class="yes" onclick="change_state(this, &quot;sendreplies&quot;, null, undefined, null)">yes</a>
```

Currently this is what I have, but line 3 won't work, because of what is mentioned.

```
elem = driver.find_element_by_link_text('delete')
elem.click()
#elem = driver.find_elements_by_css_selector('a.yes') 
#elem[i].click()
```

Does anyone know how to get around this problem?

Comment: Reddit has an API.

Comment: Do you just want to distinguish "delete" and "disable inbox" buttons?

Comment: are you saying you can't tell the difference between between the two buttons? If so, you'll have to use xpath or something to find the parent, then find child you want.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use XPath to go up to the parent, then to the next sibling:

```
confirm = driver.find_element_by_xpath('(//a[contains(text(), "delete")])[1]/../following-sibling::*')
```

To break it down:

- `(//a[contains(text(), "delete")])[1]` - locates the first `<a>` tag with "delete" in it. Changing 1 to 2 will find the second, 3 the third, and so forth.
- `/..` - go up to the parent, which is a `<span>` tag, but that does not matter
- `/following-sibling::*` - go to the next sibling (again tag name here not relevant)

Then:

```
confirm.find_element_by_link_text('yes').click() # To click yes
# confirm.find_element_by_link_text('no').click() to click no instead
```

Comment: Wow, that is very interesting how this works. 

Just wondering, could find_elements also work?, making the variable confirm effectively an array of delete buttons?

And exactly what do you mean, next sibling?   

Thanks!

Comment: Yes, could in fact do that, you'd just have to take out the parentheses and number in the beginning of the XPath. The next sibling just means the element next to it. They're at the same level in the DOM tree. So if you have `<div> <foo>hi</foo> <bar>world</bar> </div>`, the foo and bar elements are siblings of each other. hth!

Comment: Interesting! I'll have to look into this a bit more. Thanks so much!